# create a backbutton in excel vba userform to go to the previous active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform `frmNavigation` which has a `ListBox1`, which will list down all the worksheets present in my workbook and I can double click on any of worksheet listed in the listbox and go to that sheet.

Now as I have close to 50 worksheets so I double click from the list appearing in `ListBox1` and go to that sheet but now I want a back button "CommandButton2" so that it can take me back to my previous active sheet.

I have created a code but its not working.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer, Sht As String

'for loop
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    'get the name of the selected sheet
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        Sht = ListBox1.List(i - 1)
    End If
Next i

'select the sheet
Sheets(Sht).Select

'reset the userform
Unload Me
frmNavigation.Show

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, I am not sure how to explain my logic of the code below, I tired my best to describe it in the code comments.

I've modified also the `ListBox1_DblClick` code event, to save the latest `ActiveSheet` before you `Select` the new sheet.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim LastSelectedSht As String ' Variable at module level, to store the name of the last selected sheet

'===================================================================

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim TmpSht As String

TmpSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- save the current active sheet

' select the previous sheet (stored in LastSelectedSht)
If LastSelectedSht = "" Then
    MsgBox "Error, no sheet stored , is it your first time running ? "
Else
    Sheets(LastSelectedSht).Select
End If 

LastSelectedSht = TmpSht ' <-- use the temp variable to store the latest active sheet

' reset the userform
Unload Me
frmNavigation.Show

End Sub

'===================================================================

Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

' modifed code for ListBox double-click event, store the sheet name before switching to the selected item

Dim i As Long

LastSelectedSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- save the current active sheet before selecting a new one
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
        Worksheets(ListBox1.List(i)).Activate
    End If
Next i

End Sub

'=================================================================

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem ws.Name
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Its giving me error as subscript out of range on the line Sheets(LastSelectedSht).Select

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Sh As Variant
'for each loop the add visible sheets
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

'add sheets to the listbox

Me.ListBox1.AddItem Sh.Name

Next Sh

Comment: @astha when ? on the first time you load your form ?

Comment: Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
'declare the variables
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Integer, Sht As String
LastSelectedSht = ActiveSheet.Name

'for loop
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
'get the name of the selected sheet
If ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
Sht = ListBox1.List(i)
End If
Next i
    

'test if sheet is already open
If ActiveSheet.Name = Sht Then
MsgBox "This sheet is already open!"
Exit Sub
End If


'select the sheet
Sheets(Sht).Select

'reset the userform
Unload Me
frmNavigation.Show
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim TmpSht As String

TmpSht = ActiveSheet.Name ' <-- save the current active sheet

' select the previous sheet (stored in LastSelectedSht)
Sheets(LastSelectedSht).Select
LastSelectedSht = TmpSht ' <-- use the temp variable to store the latest active sheet
' reset the userform
Unload Me
frmNavigation.Show
End Sub

Comment: @astha what are you commenting here ? you need to take my entire code, and replace yours ?  or either share the rest of your relevant code

Comment: When the userform is initialise then I have used the firs code and Its working absolutely fine. To double click and go to the sheet listed in the listbox I have used the second code and it also works absoulutely fine. Its just when I wrote the third code to add a BACK button its giving me error

Comment: Your first code is working but second one to add a back button is not working its giving the above mentioned error

Comment: @astha copy the exact code above  that works for me, try to copy the entire code (I've updated a bit) from above, and see what you get

Comment: The initialise userform code I have used to list all the sheet names

Comment: @astha I have to call it for the night, clear your entire user_from code and copy the code from my answer, see if it works. If not, let me know how it errors, and I'll see if I can figure out why it's not working on your end

Comment: I am toggling through the sheets through listbox still its giving me message Error, no sheet stored , is it your first time running ?

Comment: I tried again wioth your code its working but is it possible to link it with my listbox actually when I am selecting any sheet from the listbox that sheet name is highlighted in the lisbox but now when I am using this back button it is taking me to the previous active sheet, however that previous active sheet is not highlighted in the listbox